# RDKit: how to check molecules for exact match?

Tags: rdkit, cheminformatics

I'm using RDKit and trying to check molecules for exact match.
After using `Chem.MolFromSmiles()` the expression `m == p` apparently doesn't lead to the desired result.
Of course, I can check whether `p` is a substructure of `m` and whether `m` is a substructure of `p`. But to me this looks too complicated. I couldn't find or overlooked a code example for exact match in the RDKit-documentation. How do I do this correctly? Thank you for hints.

**Code:**

```
from rdkit import Chem

myPattern = 'c1ccc2c(c1)c3ccccc3[nH]2'          # Carbazole
myMolecule = 'C1=CC=C2C(=C1)C3=CC=CC=C3N2'      # Carbazole

m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(myMolecule)
p = Chem.MolFromSmiles(myPattern)

print(m == p)                    # returns False, first (unsuccessful) attempt to check for identity

print(m.HasSubstructMatch(p))    # returns True
print(p.HasSubstructMatch(m))    # returns True
print(m.HasSubstructMatch(p) and p.HasSubstructMatch(m))    # returns True, so are the molecules identical?
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the fingerprinting options in rdkit?

Comment: Surprised to see that such a function doesn't exist yet!

Comment: I think that your test (m.HasSubstructMatch(p) and p.HasSubstructMatch(m)) is a good test for equality.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To check if two different SMILES represent the same molecule you can canonicalize the SMILES.

```
from rdkit import Chem

myPattern = 'c1ccc2c(c1)c3ccccc3[nH]2'
myMolecule = 'C1=CC=C2C(=C1)C3=CC=CC=C3N2'

a = Chem.CanonSmiles(myPattern)
b = Chem.CanonSmiles(myMolecule)

print(a)
'c1ccc2c(c1)[nH]c1ccccc12'

print(b)
'c1ccc2c(c1)[nH]c1ccccc12'

print(a==b)
True
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Ok, I'm not sure but my guess would be that creating two canonical SMILES is probably less computationally intensive than searching twice for substructure?!

Comment: @theozh I made a quick test with 5k SMILES, and your substructure solution was a bit faster.

Comment: While this is one way, going from rdkit molecules to canonical SMILES is probably overkill.

Answer (score 7):

My RDKit knowledge isn't great and their documentation is famously terrible but I have done this kind of thing myself. A (perhaps over-engineered) method would be to generate a graph with networkx and just compare the nodes and edges.

This is surprisingly simple, using rdkit to read the file/smiles string then just generate the topology on the fly. If you generate an rdkit_mol object from a smiles string as you have above, you would then do:

```py
import networkx as nx


def topology_from_rdkit(rdkit_molecule):

    topology = nx.Graph()
    for atom in rdkit_molecule.GetAtoms():
        # Add the atoms as nodes
        topology.add_node(atom.GetIdx())

        # Add the bonds as edges
        for bonded in atom.GetNeighbors():
            topology.add_edge(atom.GetIdx(), bonded.GetIdx())

    return topology


def is_isomorphic(topology1, topology2):
    return nx.is_isomorphic(topology1, topology2)
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. However, yet another extra package seems to be an overkill to me...

Comment: This is not reasonable.

Comment: Love the creative solution. I ended up using this script because I was only interested in the connectivity. One thing to be careful of - this snippet checks matching graph topology but if you substitute an N for an S, for example, it will still say the molecules are the same.